# Aws ec2 user data script not working on start up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-userdata

I am trying to run a script on my EC2 at startup, with an image I created that runs ubuntu.

However, the script is failing although when I connect through ssh and run the script it is working.

My user data is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash    
echo '
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
sudo apt-get update
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo sed -i 's/oldurl/newurl/g' 000-default.conf
sudo sed -i 's/oldurl/newurl/g' 000-default.conf
sudo certbot --apache -d url1 -d url2
sudo systemctl restart apache2' > init-ssl.sh
sleep 2 & init-ssl.sh
```

[image: Cloud-init output1]

I stopped my instance and changed my user data to something simple like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo 'work' > try1.txt
```

I didn't see an error but I also didn't see my new `try1.txt` file.

Comment: Why are you wanting to save the script to `try1.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

A script passed via User Data will only be executed on the **first boot** of the instance. (Actually, the first boot per Instance ID.)

If you want to debug the script, the log file is available in:

```
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```

Your attempt to redirect to a file with `echo ' ... ' >init-ssl.sh` is being thwarted by the fact that the script *also* contains a single quote (`'`), which is closing the `echo` early. You should use different quotes to avoid this happening. Or, as @Mornor points out, simply run the script directly. If you want to sleep for a bit up-front, then just put the `sleep()` at the start of the script.

Comment: I guess you want to create a script before executing it? ```echo '...' > init_ssl.sh``` is not necessary. Just execute the script directly, no need to output it into a file first.

Comment: Oh! I hadn't realised that is what they are doing. The quotes will ruin things. I'll update my answer.